# How do I read the value from an xml string in db2

Tags: sql, xml, db2

I have a xml string in a column called "RawData" from table "Inbound", I have to read value "Success" from an element called "status".

xmlstring:

```xml
<InboundMessage><Transaction><Status>Success</Status></Transaction></InboundMessage>
```

Comment: XML String: <InboundMessage><Transaction><Status>Success</Status></Transaction></InboundMessage>

Comment: I'm using DB2, sorry I'm beginner in SQL

Answer (score 0):

1. Regex: `<Status>(\w*)<\/Status>`.  Java code:

```
String in = "<InboundMessage><Transaction><Status>Success</Status></Transaction></InboundMessage>";
Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("<Status>(\\w*)<\\/Status>");
Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(in);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

2. XML parse lib, like dom4j. Java code:

```
String in = "<InboundMessage><Transaction><Status>Success</Status></Transaction></InboundMessage>";
Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(in);
Node node = document.selectSingleNode("//InboundMessage//Transaction//Status");
System.out.println(node.getText());
```

3. Sql if you want. Mysql:

```
SELECT ExtractValue(RawData, '//InboundMessage//Transaction//Status') from Inbound;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually I'm looking for  DB2 Sql query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , actually I'm looking for DB2 Sql query @tianzhipeng